# Position div side by side with css

Tags: html, css

I have this simple Layout in my page

```
 <div id="content-wrap">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="content" style="height: 550px">

        </div>
        </form>
 </div>
```

And the css:

```
#content-wrap
{
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
#content
{
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 470px;
 overflow: auto;
    width: 760px;
}
```

The div "content" is centered inside the wrap, what I'd like to do is to put another div next to "content" on the left side floating and fixed with 200px almost of width. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you want #content to align against the right hand side of the new div, or to be centered in the remaining space beside the new div?

Comment: I'd like the new div floats on the left hand of #content. #content remains centered but the new div aligns next to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I misread what you wanted. See if this is any better.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #content-wrap
    {
     background-color: #EEE;
     clear: both;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
    }
    #content
    {
     background-color: #0F0;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 470px;
     width: 760px;
    }
    #leftbar
    {
     background-color: #F00;
     float: left;
     width: 200px;
     height: 470px;
     margin-left: -200px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div id="content">
        <div id="leftbar">

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could centre align the `#content-wrap` div, then use absolute positioning inside it for the two inner divs.  You are using fixed-width divs, so I don't think this should be a problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #content-wrap {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 900px;
        height: 600px;
        background: #eeeeee;
    }

    #content {
        position: absolute;
        left: 215px;
        width: 470px;
        height: 600px;
        background: #cccccc;
    }

    #sidebar {
        position: absolute;
        background: #aaaaaa;
        left: 0;
        height: 600px;
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="content-wrap">
            <div id="content"></div>
            <div id="sidebar"></div> 
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```